# Adding tags to wagtail email form submissions

Tags: python, django, forms, wagtail, customizing

In order to be able to automatically use the email sent by the wagtail email form, I need to put some tags in front of the generated lines.
So in short, a line inside the email should look like this: "#Start# descr: somethingsomething. #Ende#".
I managed to add a "start_tag" and a "end_tag" field to the wagtail "form creator" but now I get a error when I try to submit the form.

The admin form editor:
[image: Take a look at my admin form editor.]
**UPDATE**
**The new error:**

```
    NameError at /anforderungsformular/
name 'start_tag' is not defined
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/anforderungsformular/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'start_tag' is not defined
Exception Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wagtail\contrib\forms\models.py in send_mail, line 293
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['U:\\IT\\itseite_design',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\priwitzl\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Di, 11 Aug 2020 12:32:38 +0000
```

I changed `wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py` (Basically I added `start_tag` and `end_tag` as `charFields` and added them to the panel.

```
import json
import os

from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.db import models
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from unidecode import unidecode

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.admin.mail import send_mail
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable, Page

from .forms import FormBuilder, WagtailAdminFormPageForm


FORM_FIELD_CHOICES = (
    ('singleline', _('Single line text')),
    ('multiline', _('Multi-line text')),
    ('email', _('Email')),
    ('number', _('Number')),
    ('url', _('URL')),
    ('checkbox', _('Checkbox')),
    ('checkboxes', _('Checkboxes')),
    ('dropdown', _('Drop down')),
    ('multiselect', _('Multiple select')),
    ('radio', _('Radio buttons')),
    ('date', _('Date')),
    ('datetime', _('Date/time')),
    ('hidden', _('Hidden field')),
)


class AbstractFormSubmission(models.Model):
    """
    Data for a form submission.

    You can create custom submission model based on this abstract model.
    For example, if you need to save additional data or a reference to a user.
    """

    form_data = models.TextField()
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    submit_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('submit time'), auto_now_add=True)

    def get_data(self):
        """
        Returns dict with form data.

        You can override this method to add additional data.
        """
        form_data = json.loads(self.form_data)
        form_data.update({
            'submit_time': self.submit_time,
        })

        return form_data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.form_data

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        verbose_name = _('form submission')
        verbose_name_plural = _('form submissions')


class FormSubmission(AbstractFormSubmission):
    """Data for a Form submission."""


class AbstractFormField(Orderable):
    """
    Database Fields required for building a Django Form field.
    """
    label = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('label'),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_('The label of the form field')
    )
    field_type = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('field type'), max_length=16, choices=FORM_FIELD_CHOICES)
    required = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('required'), default=True)
    choices = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('choices'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Comma separated list of choices. Only applicable in checkboxes, radio and dropdown.')
    )
    default_value = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('default value'),
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Default value. Comma separated values supported for checkboxes.')
    )
    help_text = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('help text'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    start_tag = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('start_tag'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    end_tag = models.CharField(verbose_name =_('end_tag'), max_length=255, blank=True)

    @property
    def clean_name(self):
        # unidecode will return an ascii string while slugify wants a
        # unicode string on the other hand, slugify returns a safe-string
        # which will be converted to a normal str
        return str(slugify(str(unidecode(self.label))))

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('label'),
        FieldPanel('help_text'),
        FieldPanel('required'),
        FieldPanel('field_type', classname="formbuilder-type"),
        FieldPanel('choices', classname="formbuilder-choices"),
        FieldPanel('default_value', classname="formbuilder-default"),
        FieldPanel('start_tag'),
        FieldPanel('end_tag'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['sort_order']


class AbstractForm(Page):
    """
    A Form Page. Pages implementing a form should inherit from it
    """

    base_form_class = WagtailAdminFormPageForm

    form_builder = FormBuilder

    submissions_list_view_class = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not hasattr(self, 'landing_page_template'):
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(self.template)
            self.landing_page_template = name + '_landing' + ext

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_form_fields(self):
        """
        Form page expects `form_fields` to be declared.
        If you want to change backwards relation name,
        you need to override this method.
        """

        return self.form_fields.all()

    def get_data_fields(self):
        """
        Returns a list of tuples with (field_name, field_label).
        """

        data_fields = [
            ('submit_time', _('Submission date')),
        ]
        data_fields += [
            (field.clean_name, field.label)
            for field in self.get_form_fields()
        ]

        return data_fields

    def get_form_class(self):
        fb = self.form_builder(self.get_form_fields())
        return fb.get_form_class()

    def get_form_parameters(self):
        return {}

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form_params = self.get_form_parameters()
        form_params.update(kwargs)

        return form_class(*args, **form_params)

    def get_landing_page_template(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.landing_page_template

    def get_submission_class(self):
        """
        Returns submission class.

        You can override this method to provide custom submission class.
        Your class must be inherited from AbstractFormSubmission.
        """

        return FormSubmission

    def get_submissions_list_view_class(self):
        from .views import SubmissionsListView
        return self.submissions_list_view_class or SubmissionsListView

    def process_form_submission(self, form):
        """
        Accepts form instance with submitted data, user and page.
        Creates submission instance.

        You can override this method if you want to have custom creation logic.
        For example, if you want to save reference to a user.
        """

        return self.get_submission_class().objects.create(
            form_data=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
            page=self,
        )

    def render_landing_page(self, request, form_submission=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Renders the landing page.

        You can override this method to return a different HttpResponse as
        landing page. E.g. you could return a redirect to a separate page.
        """
        context = self.get_context(request)
        context['form_submission'] = form_submission
        return TemplateResponse(
            request,
            self.get_landing_page_template(request),
            context
        )

    def serve_submissions_list_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns list submissions view for admin.

        `list_submissions_view_class` can bse set to provide custom view class.
        Your class must be inherited from SubmissionsListView.
        """
        view = self.get_submissions_list_view_class().as_view()
        return view(request, form_page=self, *args, **kwargs)

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.get_form(request.POST, request.FILES, page=self, user=request.user)

            if form.is_valid():
                form_submission = self.process_form_submission(form)
                return self.render_landing_page(request, form_submission, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            form = self.get_form(page=self, user=request.user)

        context = self.get_context(request)
        context['form'] = form
        return TemplateResponse(
            request,
            self.get_template(request),
            context
        )

    preview_modes = [
        ('form', _('Form')),
        ('landing', _('Landing page')),
    ]

    def serve_preview(self, request, mode):
        if mode == 'landing':
            request.is_preview = True
            return self.render_landing_page(request)
        else:
            return super().serve_preview(request, mode)


class AbstractEmailForm(AbstractForm):
    """
    A Form Page that sends email. Pages implementing a form to be send to an email should inherit from it
    """

    to_address = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('to address'), max_length=255, blank=True,
        help_text=_("Optional - form submissions will be emailed to these addresses. Separate multiple addresses by comma.")
    )
    from_address = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('from address'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('subject'), max_length=255, blank=True)

    def process_form_submission(self, form):
        submission = super().process_form_submission(form)
        if self.to_address:
            self.send_mail(form)
        return submission

    def send_mail(self, form):
        addresses = [x.strip() for x in self.to_address.split(',')]
        content = []
        for field in form:
            value = field.value()
            if isinstance(value, list):
                value = ', '.join(value)
            content.append('{}: {}'.format(start_tag, field.label, value, end_tag))
        content = '\n'.join(content)
        send_mail(self.subject, content, addresses, self.from_address,)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I guess the problem occurs when trying to send the mail.
The form-website loads and I can fill in any fields. But when I try to submit I get the error.

```
content.append('{}: {}'.format(start_tag, field.label, value, end_tag))
```

My guess is that I call the variables in a wrong way, but I can't figure how to do it correctly.

I hope I explained my problem well. I'm happy about any help I can get.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a well asked question! In the future, please avoid using images for showing error messages. You might also refer to the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As I see..
the first issue is in this
`content.append('{}: {}'.format(start_tag, field.label, value, end_tag))`
got 4 arguments while you provided only two **Curly brackets** only,plus, you didn't import the ((start_tag)) nor ((end_tag)), because you defined them in a different model (as fields) but you called them in the different model that you combined them with **field.label** and the **value**,
hint: if still you get an error,you should probably check tyopos (writing mistakes)

Comment: another advice for you, instead you modify the core modules, inherit them and overwrite the methods better !!

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I already figured out the curly brackets.
How do I import my new fields? I mean, I can't see where "field.label" gets imported.
I'll also try overwriting the moduls instead of changing them.. I can just copy the whole thing, right?

Comment: @Lukas yes you can copy everything within a model (not a module), ad about the "field.lable", you can use the "verbose_name" keyword (unless you're talking about the Django form field, hens the answer should be the keyword argument "label" ), both of them you can assign, therefore you may be not need to call it into any templates, but if you do need, so call your field variable, not the field label..!

Comment: Thank you for your help again!
So when creating the "start_tag" and "end_tag" variable, I have to assign them a "verbose_name", which I can then use in other classes?

Comment: @Lukas you may miss understood me, or I miss understood you, can you tell us what exactly you intend to do with this app? and if you're following a specific documentation, copy the link, please

Comment: Sadly I don't have any documentation to my problem.
I try to edit the WagtailEmailForm (and all the other modules that I need for that).
Each formfield has some attributes, f.e. label, type, help text,... that the user can customize. I intend to add two more. A "start_tag" and a "end_tag". I already managed to do that, at least I can customize it when creating the form, but when someone tries to submit the form, it doesn't work. This is because I want the tags to be used when generating the email. The standard email looks something like this: "label": "value" *linebreak* "label": "value" ...

Comment: ... and so on. Now comes the tricky part I guess:
I want to use the "start_tag" and "end_tag" when generating the email. So instead of this: "label": "value" linebreak "label": "value"..., I want to do this: "start_tag""label": "value""end_tag" linebreak "start_tag""label": "value""end_tag"...

Since my problem occured when the system tries to send the email, I know that I call the variables "start/end_tag" in a wrong way. As u said, I try to call a variable of a different module. I am confused since the variable "field.label" can be called, but not "field.start_tag",etc. I hope this helps

Comment: ... I need to do this, because we want to take the answers of the form and "feed" it into another system, that sorts the inputs with these tags. For example a "one line" email how I want it to be, would look something like this:
" [StartFirstName]Name: Lukas[EndFirstName]

Comment: you can do that plenty ways, one of them is the decorators,  and another one is to save the field into another variables and adds the tags you need, using the format function variable_x = 'start_tag' + str(field) +'end_tag'

Comment: or using if statement to return any value (as fabrication) that you want

Comment: by format function I meant like the following: f'tage_1 (field) tag_2'    so you can pass this to any variable or final field saving function

Answer (score 0):

for this

> *(and so on. Now comes the tricky part I guess: I want to use the "start_tag" and "end_tag" when generating the email. So instead of
> this: "label": "value" linebreak "label": "value"..., I want to do
> this: "start_tag""label": "value""end_tag" linebreak
> "start_tag""label": "value""end_tag"... Since my problem occured when
> the system tries to send the email, I know that I call the variables
> "start/end_tag" in a wrong way. As u said, I try to call a variable of
> a different module. I am confused since the variable "field.label" can
> be called, but not "field.start_tag",etc. I hope this helps)*

the best way (my opinion) is to create your decorator and wrap your latest needed dict into it.

*For your info: the Emailing process has nothing to do with what you need..!*